# Creating groups of numbering pages in fPDF/tfPDF

Tags: php, fpdf

I am using [this](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/0ukattd50gqsir9/AABRAdiNxMwBIKJF3tf2wiiya?dl=0) add on which helps me create different groups of pages. I have 2 major problems. First I am using `PHP 7.3` and I don't want to use an older version of `PHP` because I have other code that is working with `PHP 7.3`. First problem comes on **line 33** file - **pagegroup.php**:

```
$n = sizeof($this->PageGroups) + 1;
```

I am getting error

> sizeof(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements Countable

I tried to change **this line** with those code:

```
if (empty($this->PageGroups)) {
    $n = 1;
} else {
    $n = count($this->PageGroups)+1;
}
```

Can someone confirm me this is working fine, because my second problem is when I put **this code**:

```
require 'lib/pagegroup.php';

class MYPDF extends PDF_PageGroup {
    function Header() {
        $this->Cell(0, 6, 'Page '.$this->GroupPageNo().'/'.$this->PageGroupAlias(), 0, 0, 'C');
    }

    for ($i = 0; $i < 2; $i++) {

    $pdf->StartPageGroup();
    $pdf->AddPage();

    // some other code ...
    }
}
```

**GroupPageNo** is working great, but **PageGroupAlias** is returning `{nb1}` and for group page 2 it is returning `{nb2}`. So I end up having `1/{nb1}` and `1/{nb2}` and the final result should be `1/1` and `1/1` for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I manage to make it work under PHP 7.3. This is my working code inside method **_beginpage** I changed this line:

```
$n = sizeof($this->PageGroups)+1;
```

With those lines:

```
if (empty($this->PageGroups)) {
    $n = 1;
} else {
    $n = count($this->PageGroups) + 1;
}
```

Other most important thing is that it had to be set the font family to **Arial** other way it was not working and it was showing `{nb2}`. So it should be something like that.

```
require 'lib/pagegroup.php';

class MYPDF extends PDF_PageGroup {
    function Header() {
        $this->AddFont('DejaVuSans', '', 'DejaVuSans.ttf', true);
        $this->SetFont('Arial', '', 10);
        $this->Cell(0, 6, 'Page '.$this->GroupPageNo().'/'.$this->PageGroupAlias(), 0, 0, 'C');
        // change the font to the one you want to use in my case DajaVu
        $this->SetFont('DejaVuSans', '', 16);
    }

    for ($i = 0; $i < 2; $i++) {

    $pdf->StartPageGroup();
    $pdf->AddPage();

    // some other code ...
    }
}
```